# Simplification of trivial Im[] term

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Why is the following expression not simplifying?

```
Assuming[U \[Element] Reals, Simplify[Im[Sqrt[16 + U^2]]]]
```

It returns

```
Im[Sqrt[16 + U^2]]
```

while I would expect

```
0
```

What is going wrong? I am using Mathematica 11.2. Thanks

Comment: [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html).

Comment: On 11.3 I get `0`. `Simplify` tends to be a bit unpredictable, while `FullSimplify` can be slow. If you have a particular sort of rewrite in mind, it's generally better to use a specific function like `ComplexExpand`, `Together`, `Cancel`, etc.

Comment: we also get 0 in version 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation of Simplify](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html):

> FullSimplify does more extensive simplification than Simplify.

`FullSimplify` applies a wider range of transformations that yields the result you are looking for:

```
Assuming[U \[Element] Reals, FullSimplify[Im[Sqrt[16 + U^2]]]]
(*0*)
```